# my laptop screen is too dark

Tags: windows, display, brightness

I just re-installed Windows 7 today and my screen is just too dark I can't hardly see anything. I noticed that the brightness buttons on the keyboard are not working. So I went to the **Control panel→Windows Mobility Center** and under **Display** it says that there's no display connected.

I even installed all of the Windows updates but it didn't help at all. This has happened before when I re-installed Windows but it went well after installing Windows updates but this time it doesn't work. The screen is way too dimmed. Is there any work around for this?

I have an `LG R405` with a standard built in video card. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed all the OEM specific drivers?

Comment: i did a backup of all windows original drivers and then after formatting i just restored them. It didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Operating System, **Windows 7 Swedish**. There seems to be incompatibility between the OS and my `LG R405 Laptop` because I installed that same OS on another laptop and it's working smoothly. The solution was to install another OS **Windows 7 English** and the problem was gone.